# execution of shell script using Oozie, job always in running state only

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie

I need help with oozie, i am trying to run a script which creates a HDFS folder, when i execute Oozie it shows in Running state only, can anyone please help me to identify as if anything wrong with my workflow.xml or jo.properties. I tried validating workflow.xml and it did not show any error.

**workflow.xml**

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.3' name='shell-wf'>
  <start to='shell1' />
  <action name='shell1'>
 <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
  <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker> 
  <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node> 
  <exec>/user/nathalok/run.sh</exec>  
  <file>/user/nathalok/run.sh#run.sh</file> 
  </shell>
       <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

**Job.properties**

```
nameNode=hdfs://myserver:8020
jobTracker=myserver.com:8032
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://myserver/user/nathalok
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath= hdfs://myserver/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20150312161328/oozie
user.name=oozie
```

**Executed commands as below in order:**

```
-bash-4.1$ oozie job -oozie http://myserver.com:11000/oozie -config job.properties -submit
job: 0000209-150501165011472-oozie-oozi-W

-bash-4.1$ oozie job -oozie http://myserver.com:11000/oozie -start 0000209-150501165011472-oozie-oozi-W

-bash-4.1$ oozie job -oozie http://myserver.com:11000/oozie -info 0000209-150501165011472-oozie-oozi-W
Job ID : 0000209-150501165011472-oozie-oozi-W
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workflow Name : shell-wf
App Path      : hdfs://hdfspath/user/userid
Status        : RUNNING
Run           : 0
User          : userid
Group         : -
Created       : 2015-05-06 12:16 GMT
Started       : 2015-05-06 12:16 GMT
Last Modified : 2015-05-06 12:16 GMT
Ended         : -
CoordAction ID: -

Actions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                                                            Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000209-150501165011472-oozie-oozi-W@:start:                                  OK        -                      OK         -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000209-150501165011472-oozie-oozi-W@shell1                                   PREP      -                      -          -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Oozie, you don't need to use shell script to create HDFS folder , instead use the build in [Fs (HDFS) action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action) -

For example:

```
<action name="createFolder">
    <fs>
        <mkdir path="/my/folder" />
    </fs>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Comment: As of now i ahve added only folder creation command , i am going to add a big script which does data processing in reality. The main issue is i am able to run the script from HUE but getting issue when running from backend.

Comment: @Mzf Hello. Do you know the reason why OOZIE shell workflow stuck in the running state? Is this expected behavior?